# Variable Dependency Graph for C++ code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, graph

Is there any tool out there that can enable me to clearly see where variables are being used in C/C++ using Visual Studio? I need to refactor and eliminate certain variables. Manually hunting them down isn't always the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the variable in question. Click on "find all references" in the pop-up menu.

Comment: It's funny, I tried it and I get "They symbol 'xxxx' is not referenced" even though it's all over the code

Comment: @gl3829: Hmm...perhaps you need to compile the code (perhaps with debug info) for it to work?

Comment: @gl3829: That is strange. At least for the moment I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: It works well for some global variables, but for others like an std::vector<> it fails with that error. Still, this is better than nothing (and than manually searching).

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has pretty powerful refactoring features.

Comment: I looked at it. Looks very interesting, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Change the name of the variable. Try to compile. Note where the errors are.